# Select max status from table with same id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have table

```
PartNo| Revision Status
501.   1.       Current
501.   2.       Internal
502.   1.       Internal
502.   2.       Trail
```

Want to retrieve from

```
1. PartNo 501 having status is current 
2. Part 502 having status is Trail
```

Based on status preference I need to fetch part no based on status sequence

```
1. Current
2. Trail
```

. In Oracle SQL.

Answer (score -1):

One option is as follows (sample data in lines #1 - 6; query begins at line #7):

```
SQL> with test (partno, revision, status) as
  2    (select 501, 1, 'current'  from dual union all
  3     select 501, 2, 'internal' from dual union all
  4     select 502, 1, 'internal' from dual union all
  5     select 502, 2, 'trail'    from dual
  6    )
  7  select partno, revision, status
  8  from (select partno, revision, status,
  9          row_number() over (partition by partno order by revision desc) rn
 10        from test
 11       )
 12  where rn = 1;

    PARTNO   REVISION STATUS
---------- ---------- --------
       501          2 internal
       502          2 trail

SQL>
```